# Null in Apache nifi

Tags: postgresql, null, apache-nifi

I use the processor putSql to write in a Postgres database. I don't know how to insert Null value in a bigInt field.
I used :

```
${my_var:replaceEmpty(null)}
```

but it doesn't work :

[image]

Is there a simple way to do it ?
Thanks

Edit :  (NULLIF('${my_var}'::text, '')::integer)  works fine in putSQL

Comment: What is the result from "doesn't work" ? What happend in the database, any content, any error message, just what happend? Nobody can help you with "doesn't work"

Comment: is it possible to put there a smaller image??? :)

Comment: The error is : invalid expression due to Unexpected token 'null' at line 1

Comment: what if to put this if-empty case into sql statement - seems in nifi there is no standard way to do it.

Comment: I tried (NULLIF('${my_var}'::text, '')::integer) with putSql and it's OK but I have an update in the processor executeSql and the same expression doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (NULLIF('${my_var}'::text, '')::integer)

It works fine in putSQL